# Regexp for ISO/IEC 8859-2 characters

Tags: c#, regex, character-encoding

Is there a way to write a simple regexp that matches the characters in the [ISO/IEC 8859-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) character set, but does not match anything else.

This input is the normal UTF-16 of C#.

If all else fails I could write the whole code table char by char, but I'm hoping there is a more compact way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a more compact way, but if you simply list all printable characters in the character set, the regexp would look like this:

```
var regex = new Regex("^[\u0020-~\u00A0¤§¨­°´¸ÁÂÄÇÉËÍÎÓÔÖ×ÚÜÝßáâäçéëíîóôö÷úüýĂ-ćČ-đĘ-ěĹĺĽľŁ-ńŇňŐőŔŕŘ-śŞ-ťŮ-űŹ-žˇ˘˙˛˝]*$");
```

or equivalently

```
var regex = new Regex("^[\u0020-\u007E\u00A0\u00A4\u00A7\u00A8\u00AD\u00B0\u00B4\u00B8\u00C1\u00C2\u00C4\u00C7\u00C9\u00CB\u00CD\u00CE\u00D3\u00D4\u00D6\u00D7\u00DA\u00DC\u00DD\u00DF\u00E1\u00E2\u00E4\u00E7\u00E9\u00EB\u00ED\u00EE\u00F3\u00F4\u00F6\u00F7\u00FA\u00FC\u00FD\u0102-\u0107\u010C-\u0111\u0118-\u011B\u0139\u013A\u013D\u013E\u0141-\u0144\u0147\u0148\u0150\u0151\u0154\u0155\u0158-\u015B\u015E-\u0165\u016E-\u0171\u0179-\u017E\u02C7\u02D8\u02D9\u02DB\u02DD]*$");
```

Comment: The ISO 8859-2:1999 to Unicode mapping [here](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ISO8859/8859-2.TXT), includes the control characters that would make for a more practical regex. For example, your regex will not allow newline characters.

Comment: So basically you have written every character. This is not what I was hoping for, but still I'm going to accept it as you took the time.